# sed on Linux vs FreeBSD

Tags: linux, bash, sed, freebsd

I have the following code

```
cat file1 | sed '0,/2014-08-30/d'
```

inside file1, there is

```
2014-08-30
2015-03-29 + /homes/eva/xv/xvalen20/aaa
2015-03-29 + /homes/eva/xv/xvalen20/IZP/blabla
2015-03-29 + /homes/eva/xv/xvalen20/IZP/wg*d s1a
2015-03-29 + /homes/eva/xv/xvalen20/IZP/wg*ds1a
2015-03-29 + /homes/eva/xv/xvalen20/newfile
2015-03-29 + /homes/eva/xv/xvalen20/wgdsa
```

on Linux machine, the output is the same as file1 except for the first line (that's what I'm aiming for). On FreeBSD machine, output is exactly the same as file1 content.

I have found some sites about difference between the seds, but I can't figure out this one.

Comment: You might try the `-r` option - supposed to make it act mor elike gnu sed. Not sure if that is just wrt regex or addresses as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSD `sed` as found on Mac OS X doesn't like the `0` line number either.

A workaround:

```
(echo "Hello"; cat file) | sed '1,/2014-08-30/d'
```

This gives a line 1 containing `Hello` that you want deleted, and stops deleting after the line containing `2014-08-30`.  It'll work the same with both GNU and BSD versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is one of many annoying things about BSD sed.

You may want to consider using awk instead of sed, since it does not have this problem:

```
awk 'NR == 1, /2014-08-30/ { next } 1' file
```

If you want to do it with sed, @JonathanLeffer's workaround is a straightforward and in many cases practical way to handle the problem. Unfortunately, it loses the ability to edit files in place. If this is not a problem for you, look at his answer. If it is,

```
sed -i.bak '/2014-08-30/ { x; d; }; x; /./! { x; d; }; x' file
```

also works. It is more convoluted (basically it sets a flag in the hold buffer when the ending pattern is first found and prints lines only after checking that it is set), but this is a way to keep sed in the know about the file on which it is working.

Comment: Thank you, that brings new light into it. Great answer.